# In shell skipping lines

Tags: shell

I have flat file ,which I am reading by using for loop now within that loop I want to read 1st line and skip the next line. For example

```
Devicename1 Ip address model
location
Devicename2 IP address model
location
Devicename3 ip address model
location
```

Kindly guide me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `sed` command:

```
sed -n 'p;n' filename
```

Output:

```
Devicename1 Ip address model
Devicename2 IP address model
Devicename3 ip address model
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple `sed` command (This is a GNU extension):

```
sed 0~2d filename
```

- `first~step`: Match every step'th line starting with line first.
- `d`: Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.